# Regex How to remove any character that is not followed by a number

Tags: r, regex, string

How do I remove any string that is not followed by a number?

For example, I am working with a string:

```
string <- c("sb 221 reeb; ab 1355",
"sb 140; sb 14 c ab 1089",
"sb 1518; sb 1067 l ab 1770",
"ab 60 na; ab 1492",
"ab 442 aramb; ab 724; ab 919",
"sb 511 ab 416 state ab 1532")

df <- data.frame(string)
```

I would like the string to be:

```
output<- c("sb 221; ab 1355",
"sb 140; sb 14 ab 1089",
"sb 1518; sb 1067 ab 1770",
"ab 60; ab 1492",
"ab 442; ab 724; ab 919"
"sb 511 ab 416 ab 1532")

output_df <- data.frame(output)
```

Thank you.

Comment: give more example, the example is not sufficient eg `sub("\\s\\S+;", ";", string)` would work. But that does not use digits anywhere

Comment: Updated with more examples. Thank you!

Comment: in the first one, wy do you want to maintain the semicolon?

Comment: I use to separate out the characters later in the code. Feel free to offer a solution with or without the semicolon.

Comment: without semicolon you could do `gsub("\\D+ (?=\\D)", "\\1 ", string, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 gsub(" ?[a-z]+((?= \\D)|;)", "\\1", string, perl = TRUE)

[1] "sb 221; ab 1355"          "sb 140; sb 14 ab 1089"   
[3] "sb 1518; sb 1067 ab 1770" "ab 60; ab 1492"          
[5] "ab 442; ab 724; ab 919"   "sb 511 ab 416 ab 1532"
```